# Adding Specific CSS to View

Tags: views, nodes

How would one go about trying to accomplish the following under Views in D7:

Say I have four different content types (apples, oranges, kiwis, and mangoes) which are culminated into one view listing them all on a single page.

I'd like to try and add a CSS class to both apples and kiwis that is unique to each (for example, all apples having a class of "red" and all kiwis having a class of "fuzzy") but I do not want to add classes to mangoes or oranges.

How would I let Drupal know to add these classes based on their content types?

Comment: Are the fruit classes (i.e. "fuzzy" & "red") based on a content field or taxonomy field? Are they predefined? (i.e. not user generated)

Answer (score 0):

You can use template_preprocess_views_view_fields function in order to do it.